# MQTT bridge not authorised while using correct subscriber params

Tags: mqtt

I can successfully subscribe to my MQTT broker:

```
mosquitto_sub -h myremotehost -p 8883 --cafile mqtt_ca.crt -u username --pw userpasswd -t mytopic/#
```

But I got error `Connection Refused: not authorised` when I try to run MQTT bridge configured with same params in my config file:

```
connection conn1
address myremotehost:8883
bridge_cafile mqtt_ca.crt
remote_username username 
remote_password userpasswd 
topic mytopic/# both
```

Any suggestions what to look for?

EDIT:

Log entry on original broker that bridge can not connect to:

```
1580391693: OpenSSL Error: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate
1580391693: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
```

It says `bad certificate`, but as I mentioned above, it's the same cert file I use while successfully subscribing from client

Comment: @hardillb path to ca crt file is correct, I edited my question to show log errors

Comment: That error doesn't seem to make sense, as there shouldn't be a remote cert in this setup so the only cert is the one it's loaded from disk locally, which it should have read at startup.